# How to fix the 'link-time ssl backends' error? Windows 10, python3.9.7(or python10)

Tags: python, windows, server, hosting, pycurl

I started hosting my script on VDS, but I faced an error: when I installing pycurl on windows 10, it gives an error 'ImportError: pycurl: libcurl link-time ssl backends (schannel) do not include compile-time ssl backend (openssl)'. I've tried to install PyCurl using pip3 install pycurl-*.whl, but it still not work. Can you help me? I would really appreciate it.